# Multiplication by a Cutoff and Convergence in $H^s(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm trying to teach myself some things about Sobolev spaces out of McLean, *Strongly Elliptic Systems and Boundary Integral Equations*. Exercise 3.14 has me stumped for no reason:

> Let $K_j \subset K_{j+1}$ be a sequence of compact sets so that their union is $\mathbb R^n$. Let $\chi_j \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ so that $\chi_j = 1$ on $K_j$. For $s \in \mathbb R$ prove that if $u \in H^s(\mathbb R^n)$ then $\chi_j u \to u$ in $H^s(\mathbb R^n)$.

So far I know that, for $s \geq 0$, $\chi_j u \to u$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$, thus $\hat \chi_j \ast \hat u \to \hat u$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ but I'm having trouble showing that $(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2} \hat \chi_j \ast \hat u  \to (1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\hat u$ which would give convergence in $H^s(\mathbb R^n)$.

Is this even the right approach? What about $s < 0$? I feel like this shouldn't be hard to prove at all but I've been stuck all day.

Comment: Keeping on this approach, how can you relate $\hat{\chi_j}$ with an approximate identity?

Comment: It seems since $\chi_j \to 1$ that $\hat \chi_j \to \delta$ in the distributional sense.